# Generate Multiple Outputs Based on Different Mixins

Tags: css, less

I have a set of LESS files, for example:

*variables*

```
.someMixinName() {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

- variables.less
- theme.less

The variables contains a mixin for the font (for example), and I want to create an alternate version of exactly the same stylesheet, except for the font mixins.

*variables*

```
.someMixinName() {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

*variables-alt*

```
.someMixinName() {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

- variables.less
- variables-alt.less
- theme.less

I have attempted to simplify this as much as possible - I'm looking for a technique for using different sets of variables against a single LESS file.

Is there a way to generate two CSS files based on `theme.less`, one for each of the two sets of variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution you can use against a single LESS file is the idea of [Parent Selectors](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature)

With parent selectors you can apply differing rules based on parent elements or attributes.  Attributes in this instance could then be used on a parent element - be it the immediate parent or something more global like the body tag.

Then with your mixin `.someMixinName()` you can reference different parent rules:

So

```
.someMixinName() {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Can become:

```
.someMixinName() {

    body:not([data-text="Georgia"]) & {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    body[data-text="Georgia"] & {
        font-family: Georgia, serif;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

To trigger the differing rules above you would then have a body tag as follows for Georgia:

```
<body data-text="Georgia">
```

results in css of :

font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-weight: bold;

then anything that is not '`body data-text="Georgia"`' results in Arial font:

```
<body data-text="something else">
```

or

```
<body>
```

results in css of:

```
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
```